# Letting other people execute their code on own node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to create some website with games. Other people would be able to exectue their own code (upload it or use some kind of editor on my website). I want it to have API which my code would be able to use.

My vision is: games would have loops and boards and users would be able to control them to proviade unique variants. Players would be able to play these variants.

**Is there any way that I can safely run sombody's other code on my node.js and be sure that it won't be taking too much computational power?**

If it possible, is there a way to import (and remove from memory) code without restarting whole node.js process?

Comment: It all depends on what kind of code will be running. If said user just wants to upload HTML, CSS, or JavaScript (client side), just limit the file sizes. But assuming they want to run node scripts on your server, you might want to look into creating a user for them on the server (e.g. in linux you'd use the `adduser` command), and restricting that user's permisisons.

Comment: Yes, I want to run code on sever. I don't think I could do someting like this on a normal hosting. I'm looking for simpler solution but if I'm not able to do so, I will try to follow your suggestion.

Comment: I would recommend Linode. You can run a Virtual Machine with basically any Linux Distribution, and program the server on that. It would fit your needs, and it's pretty cheap.

Comment: Allowing any user to run code server side is a massive security risk.  Normally what happens with other services is that somehow the code is sandboxed.  eg.  the nodejs process is put inside a docker container etc.  Be VERY VERY careful what your going to expose on your node.js server.

Comment: I understand it, Kaith but it is only for my own education :) I won't be storing any sensitive data on the server.

Comment: Keeping things Node, and more secure you might find -> https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2 interesting

Comment: This virtual machine looks really good. This is exactly what I was looking for.